# Assign anonymous node to user Id

Tags: nodes, users

What I want to try and achieve.

An authenticated user creates a node of type 'listing' (this node obviously belongs to this user via his uid). On this node will be a link to create a new node of a different content type 'booking-request' (this link the author can't control).

Now an anonymous user can view this created 'listing' node and then they can click on the link and create a 'booking-request' node. So obviously the 'booking-request' node will belong to the anonymous user.

My question is. How can I assign this 'booking-request' node to the author of the 'listing' node after the anonymous user saves it?

Can I do this with a module or will this need custom php or both and how will I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Entity Reference Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate).

> Allow prepopulating any Entity reference field via URL

In your booking-request set up an entity reference field pointing to user entities. Then, create a link in the listing node to booking-request node add form with the right parameter to prepopulate that entity reference field.

See README in the module:

> In order to pre-populate an entity reference field you have to supply
>   the parameter in the URL.
>
> The structure is node/add/article?[field_ref]=[id]
>
> Where [field_ref] is the name of the entity reference field and [id]
>   is the id of the entity being referenced.
>
> Examples: node/add/article?field_foo=1 node/add/page?field_bar=1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way :

1. You can do this using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules), by checking the condition if author is anonymous of newly added content then add action, select `Set data value`. Your target should be `node:author`. Assign the value you want.
2. Using [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7), add condition inside your hook :

   if ($node->type == 'your_type' &&  !$node->uid) {
     $node->uid = 1; 
   }